# How to put properties inside another property? VB.net

Tags: vb.net, properties

I want to know how can I put properties inside other properties like the examples below.

Example: [Property Font Opened](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RfZeg.png)

I have tried this:

```
Imports System.Windows.Forms
Imports System.Drawing
Imports System.Drawing.Design
Imports System.ComponentModel

Namespace ClassTest_ParentProperty

Public Class Class_Parent : Inherits Control
        Public Property MyProperties_Parent As Class_Child


        Public Sub New()
            MyBase.BackColor = Color.DarkSlateBlue
        End Sub
    End Class

    Public Class Class_Child
        Public Var_MyColor As Color = Color.Empty
        Public Var_MyText As New String(Nothing)
        Public Var_MySize As New Size(50, 50)

        Public Property MyColor As Color
            Get
                Return Var_MyColor
            End Get
            Set(value As Color)
                Var_MyColor = value
            End Set
        End Property

        Public Property MyText As String
            Get
                Return Var_MyText
            End Get
            Set(value As String)
                Var_MyText = value
            End Set
        End Property

        Public Property MySize As Size
            Get
                Return Var_MySize
            End Get
            Set(value As Size)
                Var_MySize = value
            End Set
        End Property

    End Class
End Namespace
```

But the output was this:
[The readonly property without other properties inside](https://i.stack.imgur.com/98m0E.png)

I searched a lot for this, but sadly I haven't found the answer.

Comment: There are some hits for nested properties here and on the greater internet

Comment: You need to be much much clearer about what you want to do.  Properties like Location, Font and Size are objects which have their own properties.  Which is different from having them expand.  Please read [ask] and take the [tour]

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ayybcxe5.aspx

Comment: Updated question: Wait, why isn't this working? Try adding a `New` keyword, such as `Public Property MyProperties_Parent As New Class_Child`. That might or should work. Let me try and update you...

Comment: It isn't working... seriously I'm noting this for the first time in my life!

Comment: Okay, another update: it's NOT `ReadOnly` or anything... it's just that the Windows Forms Designer isn't familiar with your Class... it has some presets like Size, Font, Anchor, and stuff, but it might not be knowing how to deal with your type of data. But note this: **it works perfectly from the code!** I tried from the code and it's no big deal!

Comment: [ExpandableObjectConverter Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.expandableobjectconverter(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Thank you dude ;)

Answer (score 1):

You got the concept wrong a bit... There are things called `Class`es which are a *type* of data... like `String`. `String` is a type of data which has its own job, purpose (in this example, representing text), etc.
So according to the question, the `Font` property's type is called `Font` (`System.Drawing.Font`).
Okay, this might be confusing, so let's take something else... for example, `Location` property. The *type* of `Location` is `Point` (`System.Drawing.Point`). `Point` is a Class. And a Class can hold Properties.
Take the `Form` as an example. `Form` is also a Class which has its own properties. And one of the `Form`'s property is `Font`, which is another Class's instance called `System.Drawing.Font`, and THAT also has some more properties like `Size`, `Name`, etc.
To create a class, there are few ways:

#### [1] Through the IDE

To create a class through the IDE, you go to the "PROJECT" tab and choose "Add Class...". If you don't see that, try clicking "Add new item..." and searching for "Class".

#### [2] Through the code

To create a class through the code, you start typing one. It's not a big deal actually, you just take an existing code file, such as your main Form, and AFTER THE `End Class` OF THE FORM, you start typing something like `Public Class MyClassName` and press Enter. An example to what I mean is this:

```
Public Class Form1
    '...
    '...
    '...
End Class
Public Class MyClassName 'Here YOUR Class starts.
    '...
End Class 'This ends the MyClassName block.
```

---

If you want to know how to create your own Properties inside a Class, look at this example: (note that `[...]` means some optional stuff)

```
Public Class MyClassName 'This is your Class's beginning.
    'To show you how to create Properties, look at this:
    Public Property MyProperty1 As [New] String [= "some default value"] 'Here your Property is named MyProperty and the type is String.
    'MyProperty1 is an one-liner. These do the storing and returning of values automatically. There are Property blocks also, like this:
    Public Property MyProperty2 As String 'This is a Property block.
        Get 'This is the code that'll be executed for getting the value. This will return a value in the end, just like a "Function".
            'You can do stuff here too.
            Return "Hello there!!!"
        End Get 'This ends the Get block.'
        Set(value As String) 'This is the code that'll be executed for setting the value. Note that the data type (String) should be the same as of the whole Property.
            'Do stuff here to use this NewValue.
        End Set 'This ends the Set block.'
    End Property 'This ends the MyProperty2 block.'
End Class 'This ends the MyClassName block.
```

Hope that was helpful!

Comment: I liked your explanation about the syntax of the properties, but I continue unanswered, so I will try to explain my question better.